# Running Ansible playbook from a file in Rundeck

Tags: ansible, rundeck

I am trying to run Ansible playbook stored in my local drive. I am using wsl 2 which is where I have installed Ansible and Rundeck.

[image: Path of ansible playbook]

Playbook path: /home/hannan/wslNodeRedProjects/ansible/myplaybook1.yml

On providing the correct location of the playbook I get the following errors:

*ERROR! the playbook: /home/hannan/wslNodeRedProjects/ansible/myplaybook1.yml could not be found*

*Failed: AnsibleNonZero: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code.
*

[image: Error on running the job]

I am not sure why I am getting an error even after specifying the correct location.

I wanted to know if I am missing anything or should I need to provide other options like Ansible binaries directory path as well.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: Could you elaborate about your environment?: 1. How did you install rundeck? (kind of installation: war? deb?) - 2. How did you install Ansible? (via pip3 maybe?). 3. Rundeck instance can get/print/reach the file path? (can you print the file contet via 'cat /path/to/playbook.yaml' in a Rundeck command?).

Answer (score 2):

This error might indicate that the user establishing the local SSH connection to execute the playbook (default: `rundeck`) doesn't have executable permissions to the full playbook path.

This could be resolved by either using a user with the right executable permissions, or by granting executable permissions to the specific user with ACL, like so:

```
$ setfacl -R -m user:rundeck:x /path/to/playbook/
```

- `setfacl` - set file access control lists.
- `-R, --recursive` -
  apply operations to all files and directories recursively.
- `-m, --modify` -
  modify the ACL of a file or directory.  ACL entries for this operation must include permissions.

See `man setfacl` for further reading.